# connect database table with the local username id password of the system

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, mysql

how to connect database table with the local username id and password of the system?. When user logs into the machine. opens up the software, he gets only the assets alloted to him. asset information is contained in the database table..anyone has any idea on how to implement this.I'm using mySQLdb with pyqt4.(creating an asset manager, user gets only the assets alloted to him )

Comment: what do you mean by local username and local password ?

Comment: Again, database tables aren't supposed to change when user change.

Comment: Do you mean using the username / password of the user logged into the machine for authentication?

Comment: yes , when user logs into the machine. opens up the software, he gets only the assets alloted to him. asset information is contained in the database table.

Comment: You've already said that in your question. People are asking for _more_ information, not the _same_ information.

Comment: i'm being very clear about what i want. can you be more specific about what information you want?

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in the comments, the tables should not be any different between users. Also, there is no way to get the users password without them entering it again. And once you do have them enter it, you would have to use some method to authenticate them, such as checking it against an LDAP server.

Otherwise, if you simply want to base the delivery of database information of the current logged user and assume that them being logged in is enough of an authentication, you could simple get the login name with `os.getlogin()`

Most likely what you would just be doing is selecting on your table, data that has that username as matching criteria of some column. You wouldn't be using any sort of database-level authentication to filter the data. The authentication comes from some other earlier layer.

In pseudo-code:  `select * from assets where user is <result of os.login()>`

With regards to the reason you are getting downvotes... People would like to see more context about your problem to understand the solution you are after. What is the structure of your database tables? Are you associating asset records with users? Is there a specific need for security or simply automatically identifying a user that is running the software? People on SO that take a little more time to outline their problem, the context, and what they have tried, tend to get better responses and upvotes.